# Why does my table gat populated with completely NULL rows

Tags: mysql

im using the below query to populate a table of myn(known as **report table**) by getting out data from some other tables(known as log_table_1,log_table_2 and so on) in the same db. But due to some problem, report table gets populated with completely null rows(there are log_tables with no data) as well.

the query

```
 ("INSERT INTO report(ID, name, accountname, accountID, status, imprcount, earliest_imp,recent_imp)
SELECT  DISTINCT b.ID, name, accountname, c.accountID, status, total_impr, min(a.timestamp), max(a.timestamp)
FROM    ",log_table," a INNER JOIN logs b on a.ID = b.ID INNER JOIN accounts c on b.accountID = c.accountID

WHERE   a.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR);")
```

screenshot
[image]

can anybody help on eliminating these null rows, or to avoid them getting populated

Comment: Have you checked your `SELECT` query standalone?

Comment: yeah i did check, it works fine, for some reason in the code the report table gets data which are null too

Comment: So does it work fine or not? "in the code the report table gets data which are null too" -- what does this mean?

Comment: this insert query is inside SP, so when i give a specific name to log_table_X , if that particular table does not have data, that too gets recorded in the report table(just as i have shown in the screen shot) for some reason. thats the problem

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost. Does the standalone `SELECT` work fine? Does the `INSERT ... SELECT` work fine when you run it manually without any SPs?

Comment: warning: your query is not doing what you want anyways.  You've got `MAX(...)` and `MIN(...)` without specifying a `GROUP BY`, meaning the db is free to give you the same values for the entire table (because you didn't tell it when to restart).  Presumably you want to pre-aggregate the values from the log based on `a.id`.  The `DISTINCT` would likely be unnecessary in such a case.  Not sure how you're managing to get empty rows, though.

Comment: Thanks Clockwork it worked!!!!